# Symmetric relation , why are these symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R_1 = \{(a,b)$ such that $a \leq b \}$ 
$R_2 = \{(a,b)$ such that $a>b \}$ 
$R_3 = \{(a,b)$ such that $a=b$ or $a=-b \}$
$R_4 = \{(a,b)$ such that $a=b \}$ 
$R_5 = \{(a,b)$ such that $a=1+b \}$ 
$R_6 = \{(a,b)$ such that $a+b <=3 \}$

Those are the relations,

and these are the pairs that are given:

(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(1,-1), and (2,2)

May someone please explains why $R_3$ and $R_4$ symmetric ?

if we look at the pairs , only (1,2) and (2,1) if they're in the relation then the relation is symmetric , but if we apply those to $R_3$, $R_4$ it won't be there since $1 \neq 2$ and $2 \neq 1$

Comment: Relation $R$ is symmetric if $x\ R\ y$ implies $y\ R\ x$ for all $x$ and $y$. That means, that for a symmetric relation $x\ R\ y \iff y\ R\ x$, in other words, both pairs have to be valid, or both pairs have to be invalid. In case of $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ it is the latter, i.e. $1 \neq 2$ and $2 \neq 1$, that is, none of the aforementioned pairs are in the relation $R_3$ or $R_4$.

Comment: But in the book " discrete mathematics and it's applications by Rosen , says that R3 R4 are symmetric , I'm not sure if he means the Relation itself without looking at the pairs or with the pairs , but either ways , it shouldn't be symmetric , I'm not really sure :(

Comment: Wait " both of them have to be invalid " so since both are not valid , so it's symmetric ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the relation to be symmetric, take a point $(a, b) \in R$. Is the point $(b, a) \in R$ as well? If so, the relation is symmetric. Note that I am taking an arbitrary point in $R$, so I apply the universal quantifier.

The relation $R$ is symmetric if $\forall{(a, b)} \in R$, $(b, a) \in R$.

So for $R_{1}$, take $(1, 2)$. That satisfies the condition that $1 \leq 2$, right? Now is $(2, 1) \in R_{1}$? The answer is no, since $2 \not \leq 1$. Does that make sense? You apply the same logic for $R_{2}$, which is the complement of $R_{1}$.

Now look at $R_{3}$. Take $(a, b) \in R_{3}$. So we have $a = -b$. Isn't it true then that $b = -a$? So is $(b, a) \in R_{3}$? The answer is yes.

$R_{4}$ is the standard equivalence relation- the equality operator. So symmetric is pretty obvious.

Are you able to figure out why $R_{5}$ and $R_{6}$ are not symmetric?

Hope this helps some!